# When I try to use the filter function in D3.js, it tells me "data.filter is not a function." Why?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter, data-visualization

My data is all in one long form CSV file and I want the user to be able to choose which country's data they would like to have visualized. In order to do that, I am using the filter function in D3.js. When they choose a country as input, the program will filter out all rows that do not match the input in the CountryName column. Then, it would visualized the filtered data.

I was hoping something like this would work.

`data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.CountryName === "China"});`

Yet when I do this, I get "data.filter is not a function." I have seen d3.js code that successfully uses data.filter... why won't it work here?

Additional Info:

One of the comments asked what data is. Here's what I have for data:

```
data = d3.csv("econDataLong.csv", function(d) {
    return {
        CountryName: d.CountryName,
        IndicatorName: d.IndicatorName,
        Year: d.Year,
        Value: +d.Value
    } }
);

filtered = data.filter(function(d) { return d.CountryName === "China"});

console.log(filtered);
```

I have been doing this to see if I can get filter working, but so far no luck.

Comment: If `data` is an array, that filter has nothing to do with D3, that's just `Array.prototype.filter`. So, please tell us what `data` is.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I just added in more info on what data is.

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it. That `data` is just the XHR object (v4 or below) or the promise (v5). You have to use a callback (v4 or below) or the `then` method (v5), with `data` or whatever name you want to give it as the argument in the passed function, not `var data = etc...` like you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the docs for d3.csv (https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/CSV/).They say `d3.csv(url[[, accessor], callback])`.

You're providing the url and accessor, but no callback. There are a several ways to do what you want, here is one of them. Remember, `d3.csv` is asynchronous, so the code isn't necessarily executed top to bottom.

```
data = d3.csv("econDataLong.csv", function(d) {
    return {
        CountryName: d.CountryName,
        IndicatorName: d.IndicatorName,
        Year: d.Year,
        Value: +d.Value
   } 
   filtered = data.filter(function(d) { return d.CountryName === "China"});
   console.log(filtered);
});
```

Some more examples can be found at http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html